# Negative multinomial theorem?

Tags: binomial-theorem, multinomial-theorem

Multinomial Theorem:$$(a+b+c\dots)^n=\sum_{i+j+k\dots=n}{n!\over i!j!k!\dots}(a^ib^jc^k\dots)$$

Negative Binomial Theorem:
$${1\over(a+b)^n}=\sum\binom{-n}{k}a^kb^{-n-k}=\sum(-1)^k\binom{n+k-1}{k}a^kb^{-n-k}$$

Im look for a way to combine the two

Specifically looking to expand ${1\over (1+x+x^2)^n}$but a general answer would also be good!

Edit: I'm looking for an approach without power series

Comment: I belive the binomial expansion you wrote is wrong. It should be $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{-n}{k}a^k b^{-n-k},$$ provided that $\left|\frac{a}{b}\right|<1$. In the opposite case $a$ and $b$ shall be interchanged. Otherwise the sum does not converge.

Comment: oops, yes you're correct. I'll edit it in

Answer (score 1):

COMMENT.-If you want to deduce from negative binomial the corresponding multinomial one, then you can do successively with $(a+X)^n$ where $X=b+c+...$, with (b+Y)^n with $Y=c+....$  and so on taking all in an single expression. The task is hard I think.

However for $1+x+x^2$ it could be less tedious in what involve powers but the coefficients? A way to simplify (going to binomial) is the simple identity
$$1+x+x^2=\frac{x^3-1}{x-1}$$ so you have

$$\left(\frac{x^3-1}{x-1}\right)^{-n}=\frac{(x-1)^n}{(x^3-1)^n}$$